# Is there any Bluetooth module which can support multiple smartphone connections?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, multicast, smartphone, data-stream

We have a requirement of Bluetooth module which can be connected to multiple Bluetooth devices(Android phone) at same time.

All the paired phones connected to the module should receive data at same time.
Module:master,Phone:slave

Please suggest us suitable module which can meet above requirement.